# Problem in constructor?

Tags: qt4

Hi
I have  problem in code that the following code retuning the error that

no matching function for call to QpushButton::QPushButton(QString*&,QWidget*&)
and

no matching function for call to QPainter::drawText(const QPointF&, const QString&)

and the code is

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QPushButton(parent)
{
    //ui->setupUi(this);
    //connect(this,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(newWindow()));
}


MainWindow::MainWindow(QString *str,QWidget *parent) :
    QPushButton(str,parent)
{
    //ui->setupUi(this);
    text_str=str;
    connect(this,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(newWindow()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    //delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QPen pen(Qt::black);
    pen.setWidth(6);
    painter.setPen(pen);

    static const QPointF points[6] = {
        QPointF(300.0, 160.0),//Top Line
        QPointF(220.0, 160.0),//
        //QPointF(300.0, 180.0),
        QPointF(195.0, 210.0),
        QPointF(220.0, 260.0),//
        QPointF(300.0, 260.0),//Bottom Line
        QPointF(325.0, 210.0)
    };

    painter.drawPolygon(points, 6);

    QPainter painter1(this);
    QPen pen1(Qt::green);
    painter1.setPen(pen1);
    QLinearGradient grad1(300, 160, 325, 260);
    QBrush brush1(grad1);
    grad1.setColorAt(1.0, Qt::white);
    painter1.setBrush(brush1);
    QFont font("Times", 12);
    painter1.setFont(font);
    QPoint point1 = QPoint( 240, 225);
    painter1.drawText( point1, text_str );
}

void MainWindow::newWindow()
{
    FrameWindow *frm=new FrameWindow(this);
    frm->show();
}
```

and the mainnWindow class is called by the following code

NewWindow::NewWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::NewWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   w1 = new MainWindow("Hello",this);
    w1->show();
       w6->show();
}

NewWindow::~NewWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

Please help me.
Advance Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `QPushButton`'s constructor takes a `QString` reference not a pointer, see http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7.1/qpushbutton.html#QPushButton-2 So you should change your constructor `MainWindow::MainWindow(QString *str,QWidget *parent)` to `MainWindow::MainWindow(const QString &str,QWidget *parent)` or similar.
2. The drawText() error I don't quite get, because the signature seems ok. It is a bit unclear, what type `text_str` is. If that is a pointer to `QString` it would also not work, but the error message should be slightly different. (Also the point given in your only drawText call is not QPointF but QPoint, so I think there is something inconsistent between the errors and the code you posted)

Answer (score 0):

1) As already pointed out QPushButton has no constructor that takes QString * & QWidget * as arguments.I think you  maybe be confused between passing by reference and passing a pointer.

2) The function signature for DrawText is

```
void QPainter::drawText ( const QPoint & position, const QString & text )
```

whereas text_str seems to be a pointer to QString.
So use,

```
painter1.drawText( point1, *text_str );
```